# Where do Kotlin data classes extend from? Can I augment them?

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I've been fiddling around with Kotlin `data` `class`es and I was thinking about whether it is possible to augment some class (which contains the functionality of `copy` for example) in order to augment all `data` `class`es?

Is it possible to augment `data` `class`es at all?

Answer (score 5):

Kotlin's data classes do not inherit from any class (apart from `Any`/`java.lang.Object` on the JVM). As far as I know, there is no way to modify the behavior of e.g. `copy` globally for all data classes.

The methods used for copying, destructuring etc. are individually generated for each data class. (See [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html))

Answer (score 2):

You can not change how the Kotlin compiler generates the bytecode for data classes, so you can't change how the `copy`-function works, for example. What you can do since a recent update however, is make your data classes inherit from other classes, so you could create an abstract base class that you use for all your data classes to give them additional functionality.